"Boundary" of a Lie group
From my understanding of Lie groups, they can have multiple disconnected components. For example $\operatorname{GL}(n,\mathbb{R})$ has 2 components which can be seen since $\det$ is a Lie group homomorphism. Keeping in mind the topological structure that every Lie group has, is my understanding correct that an entire connected component is both closed and open? If so, does that not imply that there is a "boundary" of sorts (In the sense that every connected component has what could be seen as an "edge")? How is this boundary different than the usualy one in the case of a manifold with boundary, since I know a Lie group can't have a boundary.

What do you mean by an "edge" and why should it exist? As a concrete example, take a finite set with discrete topology. Where do you see an "edge"?

Yes, every connected component of a Lie group is both closed and open. Actually, this is true for every topological manifold; the group structure is not relevant here.
However, in no way it follows from this that Lie groups have boundaries. Why should every connected component has what could be seen as an “edge”? The connected component of the identity matrix in $\mathrm{GL}(n,\Bbb R)$ is the set of the $n\times n$ real matrices with determinant greater than $0$. What would be its edge?
